# Extremal of a function -Euler equation

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

I have to calculate $J(t+h)-J(t)$ where $J(x)=\int_0^1 x'^3 dt$, $x=x(t)$, $h\in C^1[0,1]$, $h(0)=h(1)=0$

I have solution, I will write it below, and I will write my question.

$J(t+h)-J(t)  
=\int_0^1 (t+h)'^3 dt - \int_0^1 t'^3 dt  
=\int_0^1 (1+h')^3 dt - \int_0^1 dt  
=\int_0^1 (1+3h'+3h'^2+h'^3-1) dt  
=3\int_0^1 (h'+h'^2+\frac{1}{3} h'^3) dt  
=3\int_0^1 h'^2(1+\frac{1}{3} h') dt$

My question is what happened with $h'$ from the integral before the last one?
Can you explain that to me? It appears in a lot of these kind of problems and I don't know why is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
3\int_0^1 h' dt = 3(h(1)-h(0)) = 0
$$